# snakemake parse output file and use as wildcard in the next rule

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a rule that produces files with sample names in every line of the file:

```
FAMILY = ['fam1','fam2','fam3']

rule extract_individuals:
    input:
        vcf = 'muscle/{family}.vcf.gz'
    output:
        vcf_ind = 'output/{family}.txt'
    shell:
        'bcftools query -l {input.vcf} -o {output.vcf_ind}'
```

This rule will produce files with individual names:

```
sample1
sample2
sample3
```

I want to have another rule that for every line of these files, uses the string representation of the line as the wildcard output of another rule; for example:

```
rule get_samples:
    input: 'output/{family}.txt'
    output: 'output/{individual}.vcf.gz'
    shell: 'python -c "for line in {input} print(line)" |  xargs -I {{}} bcftools view -O z -s {{}} -o {ouput} {input}'
```

Note that snakemake complains here that the output from input files cannot be determined from output files.

Comment: Not following where `individual` comes from in the line, `output: 'output/{individual}.vcf.gz'` given what you've shared in your post so far?

Comment: `individual` should be `sample1`, and also `sample2` etc... I want to basically substitute `individual` by the lines in the file that `rule extract_individuals` produces

Comment: I guess you'd have access to the contents listing `sample1`, `sample2`, etc., at the outset of running snakmake? What I'd do is then use Python at the start of my snakefile to make a list of the file names, say the list is named `indiviudal_vcfs` for example, and then for rule `get_samples` I'd have `output` as `output: indiviudal_vcfs`. I'd be interested in what others do in such a case.

Comment: hum I understand, but if you are from bioinformatics that means iterating through vcf files with python to get sample names, not very efficient I would say compared to bcftools. The problem is that bcftools cannot be placed at the outset of the snakefile I believe.

Comment: Not following why use of bcftools cannot be placed at the outset of the snakefile? (Since you seem to prefer dealing with bcftools.)  Python can be used there to call command line processes at the outset so you could still use that in your process to make the list of output files.